# Installation Common Data Format (CDF) library of Python in Windows

Tags: python, installation, common-data-format

I'm trying to install CDF (common-data-format) in Python using easy_install cdf in Anaconda command prompt in Windows 10.

I get error messages:

```
"error C2036: 'void *': unknown size", 
"error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2" preceded by a number of warnings.
```

When I tried to install using `python setup.py install` command, I got the same error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using another approach to install CDF. Use CDF installer from the link (for Windows) - 
https://spdf.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/software/cdf/dist/cdf36_4/windows/ 
Turn off Anti virus Firewall and then install cdf36_4_0-setup-64.exe or cdf36_4_0-setup-32.exe, based on if you want a 64-bit or a 32-bit version respectively.
Without turning off Firewall, I was getting error "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service".